# Receiver type 'FBSDKError' (aka 'enum FBSDKError') is not an Objective-C class

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, fbsdk, fbsdksharekit

Upon upgrading the Facebook SDK, I get an error.

The resulting pods are:

```
Using FBSDKCoreKit (5.0.0)
Using FBSDKLoginKit (5.2.3)
Using FBSDKMarketingKit (5.0.0)
Using FBSDKMessengerShareKit (1.3.2)
Using FBSDKPlacesKit (5.2.3)
Using FBSDKShareKit (5.2.3)
Using Fabric (1.10.2)
Using FacebookSDK (5.0.2)
```

I have upgraded the SDK like so in the Podfile and ran pod install:

```
pod 'FacebookSDK'
pod 'FacebookSDK/LoginKit'
pod 'FacebookSDK/ShareKit', '~> 5.0.0'
pod 'FacebookSDK/PlacesKit'
pod 'FBSDKMessengerShareKit'
```

Expected:

The project compiles.

Actual:

> /Pods/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit/Internal/FBSDKVideoUploader.m:78:11: Receiver type 'FBSDKError' (aka 'enum FBSDKError') is not an Objective-C class

Comment: I get the same in `FBSDKDeviceLoginManager.m`. Seems like FB does not test.

Comment: Seems to be tracked here: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/355323518445227/

Answer (score 5):

There's a build-breaking bug in Facebook's iOS SDK *again*. Sigh.

Relevant thread:
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/355323518445227/

Summary: change your Podfile to manually force dependency on version 5.2 like this:

```
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 5.2'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 5.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

The thread signaled by Xaphod https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/355323518445227/ did help me fix the problem

The solution was:

1 - First erase the pod files

2 - change pod 'FacebookSDK' for pod 'FacebookSDK/CoreKit'

Now my pod file looks like this:

```
pod 'FacebookSDK/CoreKit'
pod 'FacebookSDK/LoginKit'
pod 'FacebookSDK/ShareKit'
pod 'FacebookSDK/PlacesKit
```

3- Run `pod update`

After the update everything run fine again for me.
Hope it helps